# Is it possible to define jetty server in eclipse runtime environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jetty

I have created a REST WS application using eclipse WTP. So far, I was using Tomcat 7 to deploy my application. I could define Tomcat into Server runtime environments. Now i want to use jetty for to deploy that application, I downloaded jetty 8 and I have eclipse Indigo .. tried to define jetty the way i did for Tomcat but it did not work because the available adapter is for jetty6 and when I try to run my application using this adapter, I get a message saying  `the server does not suport version 3.0 of J2EE Web module specification`

How can I run my application on jetty from eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jetty 6 supports only jsp/servlets **2.5** specification, so you need to use jetty8 with servlets/jsp 3.0 support

use maven to add jetty 8 like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.revision}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.revision}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.revision}</version>
    </dependency>
```

where jetty version is for example this one
8.1.5.v20120716

Comment: i see.. but currently my project is not maven.. can i make it maven project somehow? would copying all my project files into the src folder of a maven project work?

Comment: try this one link http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.5/jetty-hightide-8.1.5.v20120716.zip and if necessary http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.5/ and http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/downloads.php